# GLES2.0: Use GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES via glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, egl

I would like to render an image buffer in *Java* (*NDK* is no option in this case) and pass it to shaders via `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`.

`glTexImage2D` does not work, as mentioned in the [spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt). But the function `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES` is only available via the `GLES11Ext` class, which seems kind of wrong to use.

Anyway, I tried and it gives me `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`, which should happen if:

> If the GL is unable to specify a texture object using the supplied
>   eglImageOES  (if, for example,  refers to a multisampled
>   eglImageOES), the error INVALID_OPERATION is generated.

Sadly I cannot make heads or tails from this description, especially since the Android Java API doesn't seem to give me access to `eglImageOES` functions. Neither have I found a *Java* example for the usage of this function.

Attached a small example:

```
// Bind the texture unit 0
GLES20.glActiveTexture( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0 );
throwOnError( "glActiveTexture" );

GLES20.glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, _samplerLocation );
throwOnError( "glBindTexture" );

// _output is ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pixels * Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer()
_output.rewind();
_output.limit( pixels );
GLES11Ext.glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES( GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, _output );
throwOnError( "glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES" ); // <-- throws

GLES20.glDrawArrays( GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4 );
throwOnError( "glDrawArrays" );
```

Did anyone do that before or know whether this is possible or not?

EDIT:

I had a look at `glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES` implementation and it seems that I have to correctly setup the buffer. Added that, but still same error.

Comment: Test code is available here. Sadly cannot do it like this in Android Java http://code.google.com/p/test-es/source/browse/app_image_external.cpp

Answer (score 0):

There are some comments in this page which might help: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html